# windows phone - SQL local dabatabase is not understand brush ?

Tags: c#, sql, windows-phone

I have a `class` contain entity:

```
[Table]
public class News
{
    [Column(DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", IsDbGenerated = true, CanBeNull = false, IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public Brush brush { get; set; }
}
```

and method to create local database

```
public bool createDB()
    {
        bool flag = db.DatabaseExists();
        if (db.DatabaseExists() == false)
        {
            db.CreatebDatabase();  //I get error here 
            flag = true;
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

When I run `createDB` method, It's error

```
Unable to determine sql type for system.windows.media.brush
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A list of the supported datatypes sqlite supports is located here: http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

You cannot store a Brush inside sqlite.

I convert my SolidColorBrush to hex then store it in the database as a varchar or integer if you want to do a bit more math.

When I want it back I convert it from a hex value to a SolidColorBrush.

If you want to go down the same approach a simple helper class like below could be helpful:

```
public class ColorHelper
    {
        public static object HexToBrush(string value)
        {
            byte alpha;
            byte pos = 0;
            string hex = value.ToString().Replace("#", "");

            if (hex.Length == 8)
            {
                alpha = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);
                pos = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                alpha = System.Convert.ToByte("ff", 16);
            }

            byte red = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);

            pos += 2;
            byte green = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);

            pos += 2;
            byte blue = System.Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(pos, 2), 16);

            return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue));
        }

        public static object BrushToHex(object value)
        {
            SolidColorBrush val = value as SolidColorBrush;
            return "#" + val.Color.A.ToString() + val.Color.R.ToString() + val.Color.G.ToString() + val.Color.B.ToString();
        }
    }
```